# Type variations in structured bindings

Tags: c++, c++17

Seems like structured bindings impose a "uniformity" in the type of arguments, e.g. say I have an `std::pair<int, char> p`, then:

```cpp
// You can decompose into two values:
auto [first, second] = p;

// You can decompose into two references:
auto & [first, second] = p;

// You can have two constants
auto const [first, second] = p;
```

But applying those qualifiers to one of the decomposed variables, e.g. only make `first` a constant,or mixing them, e.g. one reference and one constant value, is not possible.

Why is that? Is there a way around it?

Comment: `auto const first = p.first; auto &second = p.second;` ?

Comment: It's not possible to do with structured binding, the C++ language just doesn't allow it (it's not part of the syntax).